# textarea text not inserting to php database mysql

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

hi guys pls help me whit this option(textarea) not submiting to database php mysql here are my codes tnx. it has a Javascript function. i need to send the option(textarea) to the database php/mysql. text not inserting. or it can be numbers of how many food they selected.

**select.html**

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
<title>Catering Service</title>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<script src="js/js.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
     <form action="submit.php" method="post">
         <select multiple="multiple" class="options" id="textarea">
         <option value="foodA">foodA</option>
         <option value="foodB">foodB</option>
         <option value="foodC">foodC</option>
         <option value="foodD">foodD</option>
      <option value="foodE">foodE</option>
     </select>


         <button type="button" id="copy">Copy</button>
         <button type="button" id="remove">Remove</button>

          <!-- note how multiple select name must be set -->
          <select id="textarea2" multiple class="remove" name="food[]"> 
          </select>

          <input type="submit" name="submit" />
          </form>
          </body>
           </html>
```

**submit.php**

```
<?php
  include 'connection.php';

foreach ($_POST['food'] as $food){
     $food == "foodA" ? $foodA = $food : $foodA = '';
     $food == "foodB" ? $foodB = $food : $foodB = '';
     $food == "foodC" ? $foodC = $food : $foodC = '';
     $food == "foodD" ? $foodD = $food : $foodD = '';
     $food == "foodE" ? $foodE = $food : $foodE = '';


if(!$_POST['submit']) {
    echo "please fill out the form";
    header('Location: select.html');
}
else {
    $sql = "INSERT INTO remove(foodA, foodB, foodC, foodD, foodE) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?);";
    $stmt = mysqli_prepare($conn, $sql);
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($stmt,"sssss",$foodA,$foodB,$foodC,$foodD,$foodE);
    mysqli_stmt_execute($stmt);
    echo "User has been added!";
    header('Location: select.html');
}
```

**connection.php**

```
<?php
$dbhost = "localhost";
$dbuser = "root";
$dbpass = "";
$db = "copy";
$conn = mysqli_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass,$db);
 ?>
```

**js.1.js (JavaScript)**

```
   $(function(){ 
   $("#copy").on("click", function(){ 
   $(".options option:selected").each(function({
   $("#textarea2").append('<option selected>'+$(this).text()+'</option>');
   $('option:selected', "#textarea").remove(); 
  });
}); 
    $("#remove").on("click", function(){ 
    $(".remove option:selected").each(function(){
    $("#textarea").append('<option>'+$(this).text()+'</option>');
    $('option:selected', "#textarea2").remove(); 
   }); 
 });
```

});

Comment: what is not working? are you getting an error message etc?

Comment: @PatrickEvans tnx for your reply not getting error message but not inserting to the database. no error

Comment: I dont see any ajax calls to the php script

Comment: @PatrickEvans ow i dont know about that ajax json:( so what shouold i do?

Comment: search google for ajax request tutorials, and since you are using jquery look at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/ or one of the simpler methods http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

Comment: ok tnx ill try that @PatrickEvans

Comment: I honestly don't know why you're trying to pull in `foodA-B-C-D-E` into your DB. If your columns can't accomodate for empty fields, then your query won't work, if that's the case. Plus both your `yourFunction()` buttons seem to point to a non-existant function, on top of both buttons fetching the "same" function, doesn't make any sense.

Comment: @Fred-ii- so what should i do to send the text into the database?

Comment: You have two form elements named the same thing `name="food"` --- Your `<select>` and your `<textarea>` right there, conflict. My guess is one is being ignored because of that. Give your `<textarea>` a different name or remove `name="food"` for it altogether, since you're declaring the ID in your JS.

Comment: What I want to know is, what's this >>> `<select id="textarea2" multiple class="remove" name="food">` ? Most probably the reason why nothing's being inserted, since it's the "last" element in your form, which is the duplicated name for your other form element. I can't make heads or tails out of this anymore.

Comment: @Fred-ii-  <select id="textarea2" multiple class="remove" name="food"> to remove what have you copy to textarea 2

Comment: If you're trying to get actual "text" from a "textarea", you're using the wrong form element type. What you should be doing, (if I'm correct) is `<textarea>` and not through a `<select>` which is what you're (trying) doing now. Do read up on the types of form elements. Don't expect "text" from a `<select>`

Comment: @Fred-ii- but i need more clean option not just a dropdown list if i used textarea user will need to type a text. 
can you look this for me im looking for this function and saving to the database. (http://www.tamayos.com.ph/create-your-own-package/)then look for appetizer function. that what im trying to do:)) tnx for your help

Comment: Ah ok. I see what you're trying to do now. You have multiple options that people can choose from and move them to the right, am I correct?

Comment: @Fred-ii- yes got it right:) and insert to db can you help me with that?

Comment: You should have posted code that better reflects what's on your website now. Your website "appetizer" option for example shows as `name="appetizer_list[]"` with brackets `[]` but your question doesn't have that. Had you posted code to better reflect that, you would have had a better response. That's an `array` and I'm no good when it comes to arrays. I tend to think that if you tested that without the arrays, see what comes in. I doubt I can be of help at this point, sorry. You may need to use a `foreach` method.

Comment: @Fred-ii- ow np tnx for all your help:) i got a answer awhile ago about that name="food[]" then a foreach in submit.php but change it because got error inserting in db:) but ill try to change again the codes tnx for your help:)

Comment: You're welcome. Do analyze the other answer, and maybe Google "INSERT array into database mysqli php", you're bound to get results. Cheers

Comment: @Fred-ii- ok tnx:))) for all

Answer (score 0):

Start by cleaning up your code and making it well formed, i.e. nest it accurately, and close opening tags appropriately), like this.  For example, you missed putting in the `<head>` tag, and the `</select>` was below the `</form>`:

select.html

```
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Catering Service</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="js/js.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="submit.php" method="post">

      <select multiple="multiple" name="food" class="options" id="textarea">
        <option name="foodA" value="foodA">foodA</option>
        <option name="foodB" value="foodB">foodB</option>
        <option name="foodC" value="foodC">foodC</option>
        <option name="foodD" value="foodD">foodD</option>
        <option name="foodE" value="foodE">foodE</option>
      </select>

      <button type="button" id="copy"   onclick="yourFunction()">Copy</button>
      <button type="button" id="remove" onclick="yourFunction()">Remove</button>

      <select id="textarea2" multiple class="remove" name="food">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" />
      </select>
    </form>
  </html>
```

Later when you get good you can get sloppy about this if you want, but while you are starting out make it very clean.  Notice how I lined up onclick to make things more readable.

Now once you have it clean, look at it line by line, word by word.  Do you understand every single thing?  If not google it until you do.  There are good references to all of this stuff on the web, far better than I or anyone else can provide here.  If we solve your immediate problem we rob you of learning how to do this stuff yourself.  But glad you ask, and glad to give you some pointers.

Edit: One of the html traps and why many professionals mostly use Xhtml, and fall back to html5 only if needed for html5 only features, is that while a particular browser might work with a particular malformed set of tags, (like your `<select>` or `<head>` issues above) another browser might not do so well and gag on them.  By forcing tags to always be correctly nested as xhtml does, and which can be easily discovered with a xhtml [validator](http://validator.w3.org/), it removes any chance that a browser will or will not correctly interpret the html.  Another thing that's missing from your html is the first line, but I'm guessing you just left that out above for brevity.

Comment: You're welcome.  I added a bit at the end for you.  See 'Edit:'.